# How to call c# session from jquery and retrieve atribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session

I have a class named user that has an int id and a string name and this class is stored in a session when the user logs in.
How can i access that session from jquery retrieving the id of the object.

Comment: You can create a function that returns the session in code-behind and do an ajax call to the function from jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Use inline expression <% %> to write value to a javascript command

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var id = '<% Response.Write(Session["userId"].ToString()); %>';
  var name = '<% Response.Write(Session["userName"].ToString()); %>';
  //your jQuery
</script>
```